# php sessions custom deletion

Tags: php, apache, session

my environment

```
Ubuntu 18.04
php-fpm 7.2.24
Apache 2.4.49
```

My PHP webapp use custom function to delete expired users sessions.

At beginning of main script I something like that:

```
define("SESSION_SAVE_PATH", "/tmp/my_php_sessions"); 
define("SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS", 36000); // 10h

function session_custom_garbage_collector()
{
    if (!is_dir(SESSION_SAVE_PATH)) {
        mkdir(SESSION_SAVE_PATH, 0777, true);
    }

    $files = glob(SESSION_SAVE_PATH . '/sess_*');
    $now = time();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $mfile_time = filemtime($file);
            if ($now - $mfile_time >= SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS) {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
    }
}
session_custom_garbage_collector();    
ini_set("session.save_path", SESSION_SAVE_PATH);
```

sometimes on production environment i see this kind of warning:

```
PHP Warning:  unlink(/tmp/my_php_sessions/sess_7b2v6gipv5riclv1og0b8su9du): No such file or directory in ....
```

looking at the code above I cannot explain why this happen, it sounds adsurd to me!

Trying to replicate this behaviour on development environment lead me to nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The file could be deleted between execution `file_exists` and `unlink`, it's not surprising. E.g. when the script runs more than once at the same time.

Comment: @shingo : so basically you suggest that this depends by concurrency?

Comment: Just a guess, oh and note that the result of `file_exists` is cached. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php